# Is there any other way of creating copy to clipboard button in safari?

Tags: javascript, safari

I want to create copy to clipboard button in javascript.I have used document.execCommand("copy") this command . Its working fine only in windows . Is there any alternate way for safari?

Comment: Safari copy to clipboard can't be supported from javascript programmatically right now, as the execCommand isn't supported. The only way I have read of doing that is with flash, which is not what you want.

Comment: @GlenKeane so there is no other way in javascript for safari?

Comment: Nope, I don't think you can right now. As the answer by @Maxouhell says, try using that library they linked to, because that way you can gracefully show error messages to the user to use `CTRL/CMD + c`

Comment: @GlenKeane Okay Thank you for Answer .

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is better solution than using a library.
Take a look at this one : https://clipboardjs.com/

But i think this question is already asked, and some better solution must exists.

Comment: they are not giving support in safari browser.

Comment: My bad, so you need to look for flash plug-in. I don't think there is an other solution.

Comment: Flash is outdated...!!  Btw Thank you for answer . :)